# How to get rid of Exception The statement or function must be executed in the context of a user transaction?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, wcf

I'm working on asp.net 4.0 web application.

On button click at the same moment with different browser, I'm getting this exception. To reproduce the issue I have created multithread and able to reproduce the issue. web application calls wcf service for database activity.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The statement or
>   function must be executed in the context of a user transaction. The
>   statement has been terminated.

```
btnClick(Object sender, EventArgs)
{
foreach (string strProductGroupId in strArrProductGroupIds)
                                {
for (int i = 0; i < arrStrPosIds.Length; i++)
                                        {
                                            bCloningSuccess = m_ServiceObj.InsertPosClonnedDetailForAPosInGroup(OldPOSDetails, m_UserName, Convert.ToInt64(arrStrPosIds[i]), lProductGroupId);
}
}
}
```

WCF Code:

```
        public bool InsertPosClonnedDetailForAPosInGroup(string[] arrStrOldPosDetail, string strUserName, long lClientID, long lProductGroupId)
    {
        bool bReturnVal = false;
        try
        {
            bool bDeleteAllRulesFromPos = DeleteAllTheRulesPresentOnPosAccToProductGroup(lClientID, lProductGroupId);

            if (true == bDeleteAllRulesFromPos)
            {
                bReturnVal = InsertClonnedPOSDetails(arrStrOldPosDetail.ToList(), strUserName, lClientID);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (m_isErrorEnabled)
            {

                m_log.Error("\n ----------------------------Exception Stack Trace--------------------------------------");
                m_log.Error("Exception occured in method :" + ex.TargetSite);
                m_log.Error(ex.ToString());

            }
            bReturnVal = false;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (m_reader != null)
            {
                m_reader.Close();
            }
            if (m_con != null)
            {
                m_con.Close();
            }
            if (m_command != null)
            {
                m_command.Dispose();
            }
        }
        return bReturnVal;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Without your _button click_ code, it is not possible to help you. Show your work also. Please read [FAQ], [ask] and [help] as a start..

Comment: Can you post some code to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same message, troubleshooting it, i found:

This is mistake when using *sp_releaseapplock* or *sp_releaseapplock* in SQL Server. If *sp_releaseapplock* *@LockOwner* value is *Transaction*(default), it must be executed inside a transaction scope.

> [ @LockOwner= ] 'lock_owner'
>   Is the owner of the lock, which is the lock_owner value when the lock was requested. lock_owner is nvarchar(32). The value can be Transaction (the default) or Session. **When the lock_owner value is Transaction, by default or specified explicitly, sp_getapplock must be executed from within a transaction**.

[sp_releaseapplock (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178602.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you must see sp_getapplock sample code(sp_getapplock must be in begin transaction code).

[this link](http://BEGIN%20TRANSACTION;%20%20%20DECLARE%20@result%20int;%20%20%20EXEC%20@result%20=%20sp_getapplock%20@Resource%20=%20'Form1',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20@LockMode%20=%20'Shared';%20%20%20EXEC%20@result%20=%20sp_getapplock%20@Resource%20=%20'Form1',%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20@LockMode%20=%20'Exclusive';%20%20%20EXEC%20@result%20=%20sp_releaseapplock%20@Resource%20=%20'Form1';%20%20%20COMMIT%20TRANSACTION;) and [this link](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3202/prevent-multiple-users-from-running-the-same-sql-server-stored-procedure-at-the-same-time/) has example of that code

first link sample:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
DECLARE @result int;  
EXEC @result = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'Form1',   
               @LockMode = 'Shared';  
EXEC @result = sp_getapplock @Resource = 'Form1',   
               @LockMode = 'Exclusive';  
EXEC @result = sp_releaseapplock @Resource = 'Form1';  
COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

and second link sample:

```
DECLARE @RC INT
Begin tran
Exec @RC =sp_getapplock @Resource='MyLock', @LockMode='Exclusive'
            , @LockOwner='Transaction', @LockTimeout = 15000
SELECT @@SPID [session_id], @RC [return code], GETDATE()
waitfor delay '00:00:08'            
commit
```